# How to create a SharedResource class for localization with default localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-localization

In `ConfigureServices` I did:

```
services.AddLocalization(opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddMvc(options => { options.MaxModelValidationErrors = 10; })
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
        opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
            return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
        };
    });

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("it-IT"),
            new CultureInfo("it")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider());
});

//This is the custom service for localization
services.AddSingleton<LocService>();
```

Created the localization service in `LocService` like:

```
public class LocService : StringLocalizer<string>
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    public LocService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory) : base(factory)
    {
        var type = typeof(SharedResource);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        _localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
    }

    public override LocalizedString this[string name]
    {
        get => _localizer[name];
    }
}
```

And configured everything in `Configure()` like:

```
var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```

And in views I inject it as:

```
@inject LocService Loc
@Loc["wordToTranslate"]
```

My issue is that this approach doesn't work when there is lack of the relative resource file like, for example,
if I don't have the Resources/SharedResource.it.resx and that call(`@Loc["wordToTranslate"]`) just returns `"wordToTranslate"` even if in the default Resources/SharedResource.en.resx corresponds to another string (`"wordToTranslate" =  "Success"`). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core localization, the default language is what you put inside the brackets, so:

```
@Localizer["some text"]
```

Will render:

- "some text", because the current language is the default language
- "some text", because there's no resource file for the current language
- the translation, given that there's a resource file for the  current language

Alternatively, if you want to use a resource file, just remove the culture from it, i.e `someresource.resx`

Comment: I did created the Resources/SharedResource.en.resx, it just happen that it doesn't read it when there is no Resources/SharedResource.it.resx and the current culture is "it"; my expectation is that if I don't have a ShareResource of a certain country, it will always read Resources/SharedResource.en.resx by default, which for now doesn't happen.

Comment: And why is that? Localization doesn't loose its meaning when it's not able to provide a default localization?

Comment: It works :'D
You made me the most relieved and happy dev right now, thank you a lot (◕ᴥ◕)